# Get problem while calling a method of a class from fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity

i have 2 classes here:

#1 AlarmReceiver

```
class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
...
fun setRepeatingAlarm(context: Context) {} //the method that i want to call
}
```

#2 SettingFragment (which is attached to SettingActivity)

```
SettingFragment(): PreferencefragmentCompat() {
private lateinit var reminder: String
private lateinit var language: String

private lateinit var alarmReceiver: AlarmReceiver

private lateinit var langPreference: Preference
private lateinit var reminderPreference: SwitchPreference
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, s: String?) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings)
    init()

}
private fun init() {
    reminder = resources.getString(R.string.key_reminder)
    language = resources.getString(R.string.key_language)
    alarmReceiver = AlarmReceiver()


    langPreference = findPreference<Preference> (language) as Preference
    reminderPreference = findPreference<SwitchPreference> (reminder) as SwitchPreference
}
private fun reminderSetting() {
    // the method where i place the that method
}
```

i confused on how to define the context param from that method i called.
i tried to code this:

```
alarmReceiver.setRepeatingAlarm(activity.applicationContext)
```

but i got error "**Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type FragmentActivity?**"
how to solve this problem? thank you :)

Comment: `activity` can be `null` according to type definition. If you are sure it can't be `null` here, write `alarmReceiver.setRepeatingAlarm(activity!!.applicationContext)`

Answer (score 0):

The `activity` property is actually calling the `Fragment`'s `getActivity()` method, which can return null - it's possible for the fragment to be in a state where it's created, but isn't actually attached to an `Activity` yet, so in that case this method will return `null`.

You're chaining another call onto the result, so because it could be null, you're either calling `Activity.applicationContext` (good!) or `null.applicationContext` (very bad!). So the warning is telling you you're doing this, and you either need to handle that potential null safely (with the `?.` call) or explicitly say "this is definitely not going to be null when I call it" (with the `!!.` call)

You should read up on [Kotlin's null safety handling](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) because it's important, and it's there to make your life a whole lot easier in the end. But in this case (and most cases) you shouldn't use `!!` because there are some situations where it won't be true, the property will be null, and then your app crashes

Here's the safe way to handle it:

```
activity?.let { alarmReceiver.setRepeatingAlarm(it.applicationContext) }
```

there's a whole bunch of ways you could write that, but that's the simplest to understand - if `activity` is not null, it runs the `let` block, passing in the non-null `activity` as a variable called `it`. Then you can just run your code the same way because now you know it's not null! If `activity` *is* null, that `let` block won't run at all. Your alarm won't be set, but it won't be set if your app crashes either - this way you can handle it, or if this is a rare case where it shouldn't ever happen, you can just do nothing - it's definitely not going to crash with a `NullPointerException` at least!